# php: echo is not echo'ing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, echo

I've got the following code, and the stuff before the javascript echos and the stuff after the javascript includes, but the javascript won't echo :/

```
$currentPage = $_POST["current_page"];
$nextPage = 1 + $currentPage;
$count = $_POST["cum_count"];
$total = $_POST["cum_total"];
$progress = $_POST["cum_progress"];
echo $currentPage . $nextPage;

# number of questions less 1
$numQs[2]=6;
$numQs[3]=3;
$numQs[4]=5;
$numQs[5]=34;
$numQs[6]=17;
$numQs[7]=43;

$falses = array('false');
    for ($i=0; $i < $numQs[$nextPage]; $i++) {
        array_push($falses,', false');
    }

#  the js is how the survey keeps track of where it is
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n
            var c_name = 'whbssurvey';\n
            var c_value = '$nextPage';\n
            document.cookie=c_name + '=' + c_value;\n
            // set survey info\n
            var count = $count;\n
            var total = $total;\n
            var progress = $progress;\n
            var qArray = [$falses];\n
        </script>";

    include("$nextPage.php");
```

P.S. In case anyone is thinking `cum_count` is something dirty, it's short for cumulative.

Comment: Stupid question - but are you viewing the source when checking to see if the JS has been printed to the page?

Comment: Nice title, nice variable name.

Comment: Side note: you are inserting **two** line feeds on each JS line.

Comment: There are no PHP errors and the output of this PHP is loaded into another page via AJAX (so I can't check the source). But I do check the DOM via firebug, and everything except this javascript appears where I expect (and the javascript doesn't appear at all).
@ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I thought so, but I added the `\n`s just in case the linebreak was being ignored and they were being commented out.

Comment: Please double-check. You can actually check the HTML source in Firebug's Net panel.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario oh it shows up in the response of the POST (but before switching to the HEREDOC, the script wasn't function). PS this Net panel is the coolest thing—I can't believe I'm just discovering it. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's not echoing? It's being done BEFORE you do your include. If that include is a complete html page, the JS would be echoed BEFORE the opening `<html>` tag (which makes for an invalid page).

As well, for dumping out multiline text like that, you should either drop out of PHP mode so it's just plaintext that'll get echoed out automatically, or use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc). Since you're inserting a couple PHP vars into that output, the HEREDOC would probably be preferable.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the possibly invalid HTML. As for the heredoc, PHP accepts raw line feeds inside strings, that's not really an issue.

Comment: @Alvaro: true, but using the heredoc removes the necessity of all those `\n` chars

Comment: They aren't necessary anyway. If you hit *enter* inside a string you get a carriage return as well.

Comment: Yep, exactly. heredocs just make it easier to generate nicely formatted html blocks (with variable interpolation) and let you use whatever quote styles you want, without having to sprinkle escapes everywhere.

Comment: Hi @MarcB, the the result of this php is loaded into a div via AJAX and the page from the `include` does not contain `<html>`,`<head>`, or `<body>`, just the inners of a page. The `echo $currentPage . $nextPage;` appears at the very beginning inside the container div, and then is followed by the contents of the `include`. I look at the DOM with firebug after the AJAX load, and I don't see the javascript anywhere :/ I expect it to appear immediately after the result of `echo $currentPage . $nextPage;`. Thanks!

Comment: oh btw, I tried the HEREDOC you suggested, but it still doesn't appear in the DOM post-load.

Comment: wait I just had a thought: does `document.cookie` have to appear inside `<head>` element? (perhaps the browser is removing the script because it's being loaded into the `<body>` element?)

Comment: soo it appears that doing it with the HEREDOC allows the javascript to function, but it doesn't appear in the DOM…I guess that's not really the important part tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing without the `<script>` and `</script>` tags.  It's possible that it is being printed but your browser isn't rendering it for some reason.  If you get all the code spewed on the page, it worked.

Comment: If I remove the `script` tags, it does show up on the page. However, with them, the script doesn't appear in DOM and it does not do anything (the cookie's value is not changed and the js variables are not set).

Comment: btw, without the `script` tags, the text appears in the DOM where I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" .
        "var c_name = 'whbssurvey';\n" . 
        "var c_value = '$nextPage';\n" .
        "document.cookie=c_name + '=' + c_value;\n" .
        "// set survey info\n" .
        "var count = $count;\n" .
        "var total = $total;\n" .
        "var progress = $progress;\n" .
        "var qArray = [$falses];\n" .
    "</script>";
```

Comment: There's no difference between a multiline concatenation and a multiline string. All you've done is added some extra work for the parser to join all those little strings together.

Comment: thanks @snkmchnb, I did try that before for troubleshooting in case there was some crazy thing happening with quoting etc, but it didn't help (and just added more work for the parser).